# How to Create a Linear Searching Algorithm easier than what my textbook provides

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need help on something. The textbook I am reading that teaches c++ does not do a good job at teaching students the linear searching algorithm. As a result I have tried recreating the algorithm without using any functions. The problem is, the code I have written seems to have some bugs. Just to note I am using the Microsoft Visual Studios 2013 IDE. As a result, can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code? Here is the algorithm I have written in English. The Algorithm will not show the variable and array definitions but the source code will.

P.S. This is not a homework assignment. It is just for fun :)
P.S. For some reason the code formatting was very glitchy.

Algorithm:

1. Ask the user to enter a number
2. Create a for loop
3. Inside the for loop traverse through each element in the array and compare 
   it with the number the user inputted
4. If the element in the array is EQUAL to the number the user inputted, display a message saying it was found
5. If the element in the array is NOT EQUAL to the number the user inputted, display a message saying it WASN'T found.

code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Create the array
    int array[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int number;

    // Ask the user to enter a number
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;

    // Create a for loop to traverse through each number in the array
    //to see if it equals the user inputted number
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (number == array[i])
        {
            cout << "Number Found: " << array[i] << endl;
        }
        else if (number != array[i])
        {
            cout << "Number Not Found!" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output if I entered 3 would be the following:

```
Number Not Found!
Number Not Found!
Number Found: 3
Number Not Found!
Number Not Found!
Number Not Found!
```

Comment: *The problem is, the code I have written seems to have some bugs* -- What bugs?  You didn't mention what the output should be, otherwise the program is working as designed.  It follows your algorithm as you've wriitten it.

Comment: `can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code?` please define your **wrong**. I agree @PaulMcKenzie, it seems like there is no point of answering this question.

Comment: @plee -- Instead of writing code, you should be more exact in how you describe your algorithm.  The code you posted is correct, as it follows the steps you've outlined.

Answer (score 1):

your logic output decision for each iteration. But it seems you've to output your decision only once.

So, for this reason declare a boolean variable globally and set false as a value of this value.

For each iteration check it is found. if found then set the boolean value to TRUE.

for Final output check global boolean value either true or false and print output

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `cout` from inside the loop. Use a flag, ie if the number is found, set it to true and then write the print statement outside using an if.

```
int flag=0;
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    if(number==arr[i])
        flag=i+1;
}
if(flag) cout<<"found at position"<<flag;
else cout<<"Not found";
```

> PS: Buy a better textbook

Answer (score 0):

Easier and more fun:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int number;
    vector<int> nums{1,2,3,4,5,6};

    cout << "Find a number: ";
    cin >> number;

    for_each(cbegin(nums), cend(nums),
                  [&](const int& x)
                  {
                      if(x == number)
                          cout << "found " << x << endl;
                      else
                          cout << "could not find " << endl;
                  });

}
```

But a good starting point for linear search would be:

```
template<typename I, typename T>
I find (I first, I last, const T& val)
{
  while (first != last) {
    if (*first == val) return first;
    ++first;
  }
  return last;
}
```